# Extjs calling function from object declaration

Tags: function, object, extjs, declaration

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('DKM.BaseClasses.Stores.BaseStore', {
requires:['Ext.window.MessageBox'],
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

proxy:  {
        type:'ajax',
        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, options) {                 
                requestMessageProcessor(proxy, response);
            }

        },
        afterRequest: function(request, success) {

            requestMessageProcessor(request.scope, request.operation.response);
        },
},      

requestMessageProcessor: function(proxy, response) {
...
```

What I would like to do is to call requestMessageProcessor. The problem (maybe a scope problem) is that I recieve an error "requestMessageProcessor is not a function".

Can anybody give me an advice?

Thanks in advance!
David

Comment: to be exact, how did you call that function in your app?

Comment: Well, this should be the base class for all my stores. I want a central point for all my requests. The stores sends a request to the server (to a .php file) and then it gets a .json response back. For example I simply give back a failure msg: {success:false}. This will be intercepted by the listener (exception) and should call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition like this:

```
listeners: {
    exception: function(proxy, response, options) {                 
        this.requestMessageProcessor(proxy, response);
    },
    scope: this
},
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I get always the same error: "this.requestMessageProcessor is not a function"

Comment: Add `console.log(this)` before calling your requestMessage to see what scope it is actually run in

Comment: funny...here's what I get : Window dkm (I work with a MVC Architecture, it seems that the scope is the window object the view is based on...)

Comment: Is there a way to tell that the scope should be this store and not the window?

Comment: Usually it means you need to attach listeners not in the definition but in the constructor (like initComponent() or init() functions) - where you basically already have reference to the object. But it's also a good idea to handle Ajax exceptions globally

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that function as "global" one which is able to be called anytime, anywhere, then the way I usually do is to **create a main controller**, let's say `MainController` and define the function in there. Later, whenever you want to call it, just use

`Ext.getController('MainController').yourFunction`

If you still want to put that function into your store, simply set an id to that store and use this:

`Ext.getStore('your-store-id').yourFunction`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I set an id, what I get now is an "undefined" error (in Firebug): Ext.getStore(. Simply so, no error description

Comment: if you've not included your store in any other component's config yet, you have to explicitly create it via `Ext.create`